# While coding, an error of "name not defined" is generated

Tags: python

I was coding for the question "Write a Python function that takes two lists and returns True if they have at least one common member"

Code:

```
first = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
second = [a,s,d,f,g,h]
for word1 in first:
    for word2 in second:
     if word1==word2:
        print("success")
```

Error:

```
first = list[a,b,c,d,e,f]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you want `first = ['a','b']` etc. I assume

Comment: Looking at the error description is not always the most helpful thing but everything starts there. In your case it is very well described. There is no object with the name `a`. `a` is not the same as `"a"`; the latter is a string, the first a variable name.

Comment: he actually wants `word1 == word2` and not `in`. At least that is what I understand with *"common member"* but `set` intersections or `any` are indeed the way to go.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Why would it fail ?

Comment: Thank you..@Chris_Rands , @Ev.Kounis..your comments were really helpfull.

Comment: I hope with more practise , I would come accross more issues, which would help me to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your lists are lists of string. So you forgot the quotes :

```
first = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
second = ['a','s','d','f','g','h']
for word1 in first:
    for word2 in second:
     if word1==word2:
        print("success")
```

`a` is a variable name, whereas `'a'` is a string. So, indeed, here `a` is not defined because you have never affected any value to `a`.

For instance, if you really wanted to create a list from existing defined values you may have done :

```
a=5
b=10
l=[a,b]
```

Here, `l` will be `[5,10]`

Comment: Thank you..@Thomas Dussaut..your comments were really helpfull.

Comment: I hope with more practise, I will come accross more issues and it will help me to learn more.

Comment: @lucifer777 if you like this answer, please validate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes for strings.

```
first = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
second = ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: Thank You..@Deepika Vemuri..your comments were really helpfull.

Comment: Hope more practise would bring me closer to more errors which would help me to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Name 'a' is not defined, because you never define the Python variable 'a'. I think that you meant to compare arrays of strings, like this:

```
first = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
second = ["a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h"]
for word1 in first:
    for word2 in second:
     if word1==word2:
        print("success")
```

Comment: Thank You..@AlexM..your comments were really helpfull in solving the issue.